# Checkbox (checked or unchecked)

Tags: windows, winapi, win32gui, microsoft-ui-automation

While using automation client I am iterating over all the elements of the window.

And I want to get button...

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is code...

How can I get any of these 3 property values without running through another UI.

Comment: For toggle information, you need to get the TogglePattern from the element in question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-implementingtoggle and then call IToggleProvider::get_ToggleState method. You can check that it works if you use Inspect's Action menu. The supported patterns are displayed there and can be tried.

Comment: @SimonMourier

If I have IUIAutomationElement then how can I get TogglePattern/IToggleProvider of the element.

Comment: IUIAutomationElement::GetCurrentPatternAs(UIA_TogglePatternId, etc.)

Comment: @SimonMourier Sorry to bother you again I am doing this first time, can you give me a complete example of exchanging pattern and after that, I will handle.. means a lot thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some sample code which, if Discord is ran, will print the "Mute" button state:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <UIAutomationCore.h>
#include <UIAutomationClient.h>

int main()
{
    // warning: error checks omitted!
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINITBASE_MULTITHREADED);
    {
        // start UIA & get root
        CComPtr<IUIAutomation> automation;
        automation.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation8);

        CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> root;
        automation->GetRootElement(&root);

        // find the "Discord" window
        CComPtr<IUIAutomationCondition> discordCondition;
        automation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, CComVariant(L"Discord"), &discordCondition);

        CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> discord;
        root->FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, discordCondition, &discord);

        // create a name="Mute" && type = button condition
        CComPtr<IUIAutomationCondition> muteCondition;
        automation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, CComVariant(L"Mute"), &muteCondition);

        CComPtr<IUIAutomationCondition> buttonCondition;
        automation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ControlTypePropertyId, CComVariant(UIA_ButtonControlTypeId), &buttonCondition);

        CComPtr<IUIAutomationCondition> andCondition;
        automation->CreateAndCondition(muteCondition, buttonCondition, &andCondition);

        // get "Mute" button
        CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> muteButton;
        discord->FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, andCondition, &muteButton);

        // get toggle pattern
        CComPtr<IUIAutomationTogglePattern> toggle;
        muteButton->GetCurrentPatternAs(UIA_TogglePatternId, IID_PPV_ARGS(&toggle));

        // get toggle state
        ToggleState state;
        toggle->get_CurrentToggleState(&state);

        switch (state)
        {
        case ToggleState_Off:
            wprintf(L"state is off.\n");
            break;

        case ToggleState_On:
            wprintf(L"state is on.\n");
            break;

        case ToggleState_Indeterminate:
            wprintf(L"state is indeterminate.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort you put in to answer... I want to be a good programmer like you!!... Is there any mantra, you wanna share? :)

Comment: What about "The expert in anything was once a beginner" :-)