# Win32 click button without window handle

Tags: c#, winapi, click, inspect, spy++

I'm trying to click a button in one application using C#,
This is how it looks in the Spy++

[image: Spy++]

And I got the ToolBar handle and there are buttons under it that Spy++ can't see and they look like this:

[image: Buttons]

but Inspect sees them:

[image: inspect]

so my question is how can I handle those without position clicking?

Here are the first buttons properties from Inspect

[image: Inspect Button Properties]

Comment: Use https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141013-00/?p=43863 on that window?

Comment: The toolbar buttons probably map to a WM_COMMAND wParam ID value. Is there a way to spy on the thread message queue and sniff the number?

Comment: Get to the button element and then use the InvokePattern's Invoke method on it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.invokepattern.invoke similar to this (in C++) https://stackoverflow.com/a/68060247/403671

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Why? What's wrong with UI Automation?